# How can I count the number of pairs in a tuple such that both the elements in the pair are even?

Tags: python

For example, given a tuple of pairs:

```
T = ((2, 5), (4, 8), (7, 8), (10, 12))
```

How can I count the number of pairs such that both the elements in the pair are even?

In this case, the result would be `2`, because the pairs `(4, 8)`, and `(10, 12)` are all-even.

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: This site is not for getting homework solutions. You are expected to do some research and ask about ***your own code***. Show a [mre] of your code and explain what is wrong: Are you getting an error, wrong output? Post example inputs/outputs. You can read more about [ask] and  [How to ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Try to break-down the problem to smaller steps: Do you know how to check if a number is even? Can you expand that to check if both numbers of a tuple are even? Can you expand that to loop and count the tuples that satisfy that?

Answer (score 1):

Let's define a function which will detect whether a pair is even or not

```py
def check_pair_is_even(pair):
    if pair[0]%2 == 0 and pair[1]%2 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Now adding a `count` variable and a `for` loop, we can count the even pairs

```py
def check_pair_is_even(pair):
    if pair[0]%2 == 0 and pair[1]%2 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

T=((2,5),(4,8),(7,8),(10,12))

count = 0
for i in T:
    if(check_pair_is_even(i)):
        count += 1

print(count)
```

```
2
```

---

And if you like one lier

```
T=((2,5),(4,8),(7,8),(10,12))
sum((i[0]%2 == 0 and i[1]%2 == 0) for i in T)
```

```
2
```

Comment: The structure `if <something>: return True; else: return False` is just a clumsy way of writing `return <something>` (or `return bool(<something>)` in case it is not already a boolean)

Comment: It can also be more general by writing `return all(num%2 == 0 for num in pair)` (can later be expanded to more than a pair)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
count = 0
for pair in T:
    if pair[0]%2 == 0 and pair[1]%2 == 0:
        count += 1

print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple function:

```
def count_even(arr):
    ct = 0
    for i in arr:
        if sum(i)%2 == 0:
            ct+=1
    return ct
```

and here is the testing code:

```
t = ((2,4),(2,3),(4,6),(8,10))
print(count_even(t))
```

Answer (score 0):

The product of odd numbers is an odd number but all other products will give an even number. so we can multiply the numbers in each tuple (after increasing them by 1) to detect pairs of even numbers and then add up 1s of these odd products:  (a+1)(b+1) mod 2

```
sum((a+1)*(b+1)%2 for a,b in T) # 2
```